# Locking behavior of object in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

On every click of `increment` button:
Expectation: current `count` is logged
Reality: initial value of `count`, i.e. 3 is logged

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function SomeLibrary(props) {
  const [mapState, setMapState] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("setting map");
    // Run exactly once at mount of component
    setMapState(props.map);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapState) {
      mapState.key();
    }
  }, [props]);

  return <div> ... </div>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(3);

  const map = { key: () => {
    console.log("fn", count);
  }};

  return (
    <div>
      Active count: {count} <br />
      <button onClick={() => {
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        Increment
      </button>
      <SomeLibrary map={map} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Run here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-voice-9yic4)

Does the object in JS locks the values of variables inside it after initializing?

I want to know the reason why function in object doesn't use the current value of count whenever invoked but React ref gets the current value in that same scenario

I don't understand why this works: 
Replace the map variable with this:

```js
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(3);
const stateRef = useRef();
stateRef.current = count;

const map = { key: () => {
  console.log("fn", stateRef.current);
}};
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Does the object in JS locks the values of variables inside it after initializing?

No.

You're effectively setting state of `SomeLibrary` with an initial value when it mounts, and never again updating that state, so it continually logs its initial value.

```
const [mapState, setMapState] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("setting map");
  // Run only once at mount of component
  setMapState(props.map); // <-- no other `setMapState` exists
}, []); // <-- runs once when mounting
```

By simply adding `props.map` to the dependency array this effect runs only when `map` updates, and correctly updates state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("setting map");
  // Run only once at mount of component
  setMapState(props.map);
}, [props.map]);
```

[image: Edit hardcore-kilby-n0ogv]

Notice, however, the state of `SomeLibrary` is a render cycle behind that of `App`. This is because the value of the queued state update in `SomeLibrary` *isn't available* until the *next* render cycle. It is also an anti-pattern to store passed props in local component state (*with few exceptions*).

#### Why React ref gets the current value in that same scenario?

```
const [count, setCount] = React.useState(3);
const stateRef = useRef();
stateRef.current = count; // <-- stateRef is a stable reference

const map = { key: () => {
  console.log("fn", stateRef.current); // <-- ref enclosed in callback
}};
```

When react component props or state update, a re-render is triggered. The `useRef` does not, it's used to hold values between or through render cycles, i.e. it is a *stable* object reference. This reference is enclosed in the callback function in the map object passed as a prop. When the `count` state updates in `App` a rerender is triggered and `stateRef.current = count;` updates the *value* stored in the ref, i.e. this is akin to an object mutation.

Another piece to the puzzle is functional components are *always* rerendered when their parent rerenders. The passed `map` object is a *new* object when passed in props.

It's this rerendering that allows `SomeLibrary` to run the second effect to invoke the non-updated-in-state callback `mapState.key`, but this time the object reference being console logged has been mutated.

Comment: It is intentional to not update mapState.
Sorry if the intent was not clear, but I wanted to know why does it work with `stateRef.current`
What is the diff between using ref.current and state variable?

Comment: @Anant_Kumar when react component props or state update, a re-render is triggered. The `useRef` does not, it's used to hold values *between* or *through* render cycles. Do you mind expanding on your use of the ref and what *exactly* is swapped out or replaced, the "Replace the map with this..." bit? The way you've written it in your question isn't clear what has been swapped/replaced and what is being passed on to `SomeLibrary`.

Comment: My bad, it was supposed to be `console.log("fn", stateRef.current);`

Comment: @Anant_Kumar Updated answer with a bit more explanation on why using a ref appears to work.